# EMACS configuration problems: Keybinding ido-find-file-other-window will result in an error

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I have a keybind for ido-find-file-other-window. However, on start up this keybind returns an error: "Symbol's function definition is void: term-next-input".

However, running ido-find-file-other-window without the keybind works completely as expected.

In addition, when I open the file where my keybinds are and run eval-buffer, everything seems to work fine again.

I have it bounded like this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-o") 'ido-find-file-other-window)
```

Help?

Edit: This is the stacktrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function term-next-input)
   indirect-function(term-next-input)
   command-execute(term-next-input)
```

Comment: You should set `debug-on-error` to `t`, then you should get a stacktrace which will allow you to narrow down where the error occurs. If this error occurs on Emacs startup, you can start Emacs with --debug-init, which basically do the same. If you need further help, add the stacktrace above.

Comment: I don't get error with your code (Emacs 24.3). The error might be in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there was a conflict with some other package that already used M-o.

The solution to this was to create a minor mode that is globally enabled to always have the bind on.